# Can't boot after changing "filesystem" partition to automount

Tags: boot, boot-partition

For some [idiot] reason I set the "Linux filesystem" partition to "auto-mount on start-up" using the Disks GUI utility thinking it was my Windows partition and now I can only boot into text mode.
After GRUB I get the following:

```
/dev/sda5: clean, #####/####### files, #####/####### blocks
```

I'd like to know how to get it back to the default state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which partition did you change? Are you saying you do have a terminal you can enter commands in?  If so, what is the output of: `sudo fdisk -l` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: I changed "/dev/sda5", which was the only "Filesystem" partition.
The output of fdisk -l is "/dev/sda" from 1 to 4 Windows partitions and `/dev/sda5 ##### ##### ##### Linux filesystem` and `/dev/sda5 ##### ##### ##### Linux swap`.

Comment: As for the cat command it is `UUID=8A9C /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1`.

Comment: I see /dev/sda5 mentioned twice in the fdisk output? Did you make a typo? The root partition (/) is not mounted via /etc/fstab. Make sure what is the correct partition number for X in /dev/sdaX for the /. Then add `/dev/sdaX  /   ext4    errors=remount-ro  0  1` to  `/etc/fstab` . Replace the X by the right partition number. Then reboot.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be "/dev/sda6 - Linux swap". Adding that line to fstab did the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, I am assuming that / is on /dev/sda5 and swap is on /dev/sda6. That would mean your `/etc/fstab` should have the lines:

```
/dev/sda5 /         ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda6 none      swap    sw                0       0
UUID=8A9C /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
```

Make sure that / is mounted first !
At a later stage, if everything is working you can replace the `/dev/sdaX` lines by `UUID=xxxxxx` but that is not really necessary.